# Can not read SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Please, help!
By pressing the button, parameter 0 is always transmitted.

**MainActivity.class**

```
this.listResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dbResult.read(RssActivity.this);
            RssData rssData = dbResult.select(id);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**DataBase**

```
public class DBResult {
...
SQLiteDatabase database;

public DBResult(Context context){
    DBResult.ResultOpenHelper openHelper = new DBResult.ResultOpenHelper(context);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public long insert(RssData rssData) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(RSS_NAME, rssData.getRssName());
    cv.put(RSS_TITLE, rssData.getTitle());
    cv.put(RSS_LINK, rssData.getLink());
    cv.put(RSS_DESCRIPTION, rssData.getDescription());
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
public int update(RssData rssData){
    ...
}
public RssData select(long id){
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,null, RSS_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, RSS_ID);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    String rssName = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_NAME);
    String title = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_TITLE);
    String link = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_LINK);
    String description = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_DESCRIPTION);
    new RssData (id, rssName, title, link, description);}
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
    return null;
}
...
private class ResultOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public ResultOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        database=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                RSS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                RSS_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                RSS_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
                RSS_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
                RSS_LINK + " TEXT ); ";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to get a link to open it in WebView.

ERROR: "on a null object reference"

I will be very grateful for any help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will always return **null**.

```
public RssData select(long id){
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,null, RSS_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, RSS_ID);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    String rssName = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_NAME);
    String title = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_TITLE);
    String link = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_LINK);
    String description = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_DESCRIPTION);
    new RssData (id, rssName, title, link, description);}
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
    return null;
}
```

Use :-

```
public RssData select(long id){
    Rssdata rv;
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
        null, 
        RSS_ID + " = ?", 
        new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, 
        null, null, RSS_ID
    );
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String rssName = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_NAME);
        String title = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_TITLE);
        String link = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_LINK);
        String description = cursor.getString(NUM_RSS_DESCRIPTION);
    }
    cursor.close(); //<<<< Should always close Cursors when done with them.
    return rv;
}
```

However, if no row is found then it will still return null, so you should code accordingly for null being returned e.g. :-

```
    this.listResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dbResult.read(RssActivity.this);
            RssData rssData = dbResult.select(id);
            if (rssData == null) {
                Toast.maketext(getBaseContext(),"Ooops!!! no such row in DB",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

### NOTE

The above assumes that the Adapter is a CursorAdapter or a Custom Adapter that correctly passes **id** to the onItemClick method. If the Adapter is not such an Adapter then **id** will likely not be the **id** of the respective row rather it will be the position of the selected item.

Comment: Many thanks! It is only necessary to add rv = new RssData (id, rssName, title, description, link); and it all worked!